# iFrame remember cookie consent

Tags: cookies, iframe, cookieconsent

I have an angular application. Inside application in one page I am using iFrame to display website using src property. src can input by customer from back end. can be any website.

Now problem is when website is opened in iFrame, iframe is not remembering cookie consent(example accept all cookies, read guide lines etc. ) of that website. after selecting cookie consent, cookie consent popup is loading immediately.

```
<iframe [src]="safeUrl" style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%; border: none"></iframe>
```

example src website: [www.software4you.com](http://www.software4you.com)

How can iFrame remember cookie consent option ?

application hosting domain and iFrame src may be different.

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: NO. I did not find the answer. If you find please let me know

Comment: I am facing similar issue. why there is no one on @stackoverflow to help us with this.